# How do I make the icon to be visible in a textfield when not focusing on the field in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to create a custom class that returns a TextFormField, I also have an Icon in the field which is optional however when I add the Icon it is only visible the focusing on the field, when I click on the other field the Icon disappears.[image]**strong text**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class myTextField extends StatelessWidget {
  myTextField({
    Key? key,
    this.hintText,
    this.helpText,
    this.prefixIcon,
    this.suffixIcon,
    this.isPassword,
    this.enabled,
    this.readOnly,
    this.borderColor,
  }) : super(key: key);

  late Color? borderColor;
  late bool? enabled;
  late String? helpText;
  late String? hintText;
  late bool? isPassword = true;
  late IconData? prefixIcon;
  late bool? readOnly;
  late IconData? suffixIcon;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: TextFormField(
        readOnly: null == readOnly ? false : true,
        obscureText: null == isPassword ? false : true,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(
              color: Colors.greenAccent,
              width: 1.0,
            ),
          ),
          enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(
              color: Colors.greenAccent,
              width: 1.0,
            ),
          ),
          border: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(
              color: borderColor ?? Colors.teal.shade100,
              width: 1.0,
            ),
          ),
          hintText: null == hintText ? '' : helpText,
          prefix: null == prefixIcon ? null : Icon(prefixIcon),
          suffix: null == suffixIcon ? null : Icon(suffixIcon),
          enabled: null == enabled ? true : false,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use prefixIcon and suffixIcon to show these icon in decoration InputDecoration. You just added as prefix text.

Give a try;

```
 return Container(
      child: TextFormField(
        readOnly: null == readOnly ? false : true,
        obscureText: null == isPassword ? false : true,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
//----------------- ADD THESE Two ICONS--------------------------------//
          prefixIcon: null == prefixIcon ? null : Icon(prefixIcon),
          suffixIcon: null == suffixIcon ? null : Icon(suffixIcon),
          focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(
              color: Colors.greenAccent,
              width: 1.0,
            ),
          ),
          enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(
              color: Colors.greenAccent,
              width: 1.0,
            ),
          ),
          border: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(
              color: borderColor ?? Colors.teal.shade100,
              width: 1.0,
            ),
          ),
          hintText: null == hintText ? '' : helpText,

          enabled: null == enabled ? true : false,
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Just a stupid mistake.

Comment: No problem welcome. If it works, please kindly check the green tick as resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use prefix: instead of prefixIcon: . Its slightly different layout but do the trick straight away.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).